# JAX-WS processing of optional nillable values

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm creating a web service using JAX-WS. It is created from `@WebService` annotated class using sun-jaxws.xml.

I have a new requirement for some fields to be both optional and nillable. For such fields if nill is passed I have to write DB NULL, but if value is not passed I should not touch the DB value.

To be able to distinguish these case I'm trying to add `@XmlElementRef` to such fields, but JAXB fails with the following error:

```
SEVERE: WSSERVLET11: failed to parse runtime descriptor: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create JAXBContext
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.createJAXBContext(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:164)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.model.AbstractSEIModelImpl.postProcess(AbstractSEIModelImpl.java:94)

[...]

Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}lastName.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.example.test.Person.lastName
        at com.example.test.Person
        at public com.example.test.Person com.example.test.jaxws.UpdatePerson.person
        at com.example.test.jaxws.UpdatePerson
```

**Question.** Can this task be done with JAX-WS? If not, what is a common way to solve such problem?

Here is my minimal complete example:

```
@XmlType(name = "Person")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {
    @XmlElementRef(name="lastName")
    private JAXBElement<String> lastName;

    public JAXBElement<String> getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(JAXBElement<String> lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

And my endpoint:

```
@WebService(  
  serviceName="CustomTestService",
  portName="DefaultPort",
  targetNamespace="http://ws.example.com/"  
)
@SchemaValidation
public class TestEndpoint {

    @WebMethod
    public void updatePerson(
            @WebParam(name="person") Person person 
            ) {

        // do nothing
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665550/jaxb-element-that-is-both-optional-and-nillable) question is on similar subject, but we don't use request/response initial schema to feed `xjc`. Is using `xjc` the only way to use `@XmlElementRef` annotation?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `ObjectFactory` class with a create method that is annotated with `@XmlElememtDecl` that the exception describes:

```
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {}lastName.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.example.test.Person.lastName
```

It would look something like the following:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name="lastName")
    public JAXBElement<String> createLastName(String value) {
        return new JAXBElement<String>(new QName("lastName"), String.class, value);
    }

}
```